# Regex extract string after the second "." dot character at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to extract the second "file extension" of a file name so:

```
/Users/path/my-path/super.lol.wtf/main.config.js
```

What I need is:

```
.config.js
```

What would be totally awesome if I got an array with 2 strings in return:

```
var output = ['main', '.config.js'];
```

What I have tried:

```
^(\d+\.\d+\.)
```

But that ain't working.

Thanks

Comment: What would you expect from `hello.world/foo.bar.fizz.buzz`? or `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
([^\/.\s]+)(\.[^\/\s]+)$
```

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/aH4wZ6/1)

- `([^\/.\s]+)` - Capturing group excluding the characters `/` and `.` literally as well as any white space character(s) one or more times.
- `(\.[^\/\s]+)` - Similar to the expression above; capturing group starting with the `.` character literally; excluding the characters `/` and `.` literally as well as any white space character(s) one or more times.
- `$` - End of a line

---

Alternatively, you could also use the following:

```
(?:.*\/|^)([^\/.\s]+)(\.[^\/\s]+)$
```

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/sK0iQ2/1)

- `(?:.*\/|^)` - Same as the expression above, except this will narrow the match down to reduce the number of steps. It's a non-capturing group that will either match the beginning of the line or at the `/` character.

---

The first expression is shorter, but the second one has better performance.

Both expressions would match the following:

```
['main', '.config.js']
```

In each of the following:

```
/Users/path/my-path/some.other.ext/main.config.js
some.other.ext/main.config.js
main.config.js
```

Comment: is it possible to also extract "config" ? that would be totally awesome

Comment: @randomKek Yeah, see - https://regex101.com/r/nN4vS7/1 ... and if you don't want "config" to start with a dot, https://regex101.com/r/xG6dL4/1

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need:

```
(?:\/?(?:.*?\/)*)([^.]+)*\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
```

- `(?:` means detect and ignore,
- `[^.]+` means anything except `.`
- `.*?` means pass until last `/`

Check [Here](https://regex101.com/r/oX5aG2/3)

Comment: works perfect, but still want it to work if I the filepath is relative, so without "/" in the string like so: https://regex101.com/r/oX5aG2/2